# DNN 8.00.02 - Get current module ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke

The login page on my DNN website doesn't submit when you hit enter. After poking around in the `/DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/DNN/Login.ascx` file, I found out that the culprit is that `<%#ModuleId%>` isn't returning the module ID.

Here is how it's used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*globals jQuery, window, Sys */
    (function ($, Sys) {
        function setUpLogin() {
            var actionLinks = $("a#dnn_ctr<%#ModuleId%>_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin");
            actionLinks.click(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass("dnnDisabledAction")) {
                    return false;
                }

                actionLinks.addClass("dnnDisabledAction");
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.dnnLoginService').on('keydown', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    var $loginButton = $('#dnn_ctr<%#ModuleId%>_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin');
                    if ($loginButton.hasClass("dnnDisabledAction")) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    $loginButton.addClass("dnnDisabledAction");
                    eval($loginButton.attr('href'));
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            setUpLogin();
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
                setUpLogin();
            });
        });
    }(jQuery, window.Sys));
</script>
```

The login button ends up with an id of `dnn_ctr3927_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin` but the final jQuery spits out `dnn_ctr_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin` causing the code above not to work right.

How can I get the correct Module ID without hard-coding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug. I replaced #ModuleId by =ModuleId and it seem's to work.
i suggest you to try this modification in the /DesktopModules/AuthenticationServices/DNN/Login.ascx file.